# Need help with PHP socket server!

Tags: php, sockets, scale

Hi i am writing a socket server , At the moment i have 2 options

1. Go with PHP
2. Go with C++

---

The thing i need to know is that which of them is more reliable and scalable.After searching google a lot i found out that pretty much C++ can take care of my Scale needs but the thing is C++ requires much more coding then PHP moreover deployment is a bit harder on C++ .

PHP sounds promising (because of native API's for SQL & SOCKETS also its easier to deploy on cross platforms ) but I have no clue on how scalable the PHP based server can be.At the moment i want to support atleast 1k - 2k concurrent connections . Can PHP take this load ?

Also is there any way to implement Multithreading in PHP (so that i can part the workload on 2 or more threads rather then 1 overloaded thread holding all users and there requests).

---

Incase needed My server is a basic machine.

Processor : AMD Sempron 3000+

RAM       : 2 GB

HDD       : 80 Gigs

I plan to move to a faster server after some time .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i cant :'( my sponsors want to see the effect of the code on a scale  of a 1000 - 2000 users  before allowing me to go on HIGH SCALE with an i7 or AMD PHENOM II server .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is definitely a bad choice - no threads - your basic architecture would be to fork() a process for every connection.  Not fun.

C++ is probably the way to go, though you might other interpreted languages and evaluate them.

Before committing to writing something in C++, I'd certainly consider an event-driven server-side-javascript approach (see http://nodejs.org), or possibly something python (twisted?) or ruby-based.

Comment: will nodejs work with my windows machine (which i develop on ) ? as i need to test my code for sure before putting it on server!

Comment: using node  ^_^ thank yew i will give ya credit on the projects website :D

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use PHP for that. PHP has no built-in support for multithreading. Go with C++ or maybe Java.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has no multithreading and 2k clients will "kill" a single script.

C++ is fine, for a lot of (lightweight) tasks a single thread with epoll demultiplexing is the fastest way, if not, there is prethread(like prefork buth with threads), fork is only needed if one processor core is not able to serve all the requests. Write the socket code with a state machine so you can play with different implementations and switch between single and multithreaded behavior.

Comment: what if the php script is compiled ?. there are a few compilers for php available on internet , i think the only difference among PHP & C++ In core is compiler vs interpreter. i was also thinking of something like. making n open scripts say 10 with each having 200 clients i think PHP should be able to handle that ... if not i am going back to my NATIVE C++ ..

Comment: Yes that is an option.. depends on what you're doing. But there is much more difference than just compiled vs interpreted, PHP uses dynamic types and a lot of other dynamic features and a compiler can deduce the static type only for a smart portion of the code the rest needs more compilacted and slower (compiled) code.

Comment: i am now using node.js as guided by timdev.. thank you for ur advice too :D . and yeah C++ and PHP become quite same when used with compiler :) ..

Comment: well, practically any language can be compiled to native code... are they quite the same? :)

Answer (score 0):

on Java you have Netty and Mina